# How to Download a public directory from a Controller in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, download

I have a Rails 4 app that I am using to track if a product, in this case the product refers to Badges, that uses a uniquely generated QR Code to identify if the badge is legitimate and not counterfeit. I am able to properly generate all of the QR codes I need into a directory that lives in the public folder (`public/codes_out`, these are created on initial seeding of the DB), but I seem to be having trouble downloading the directory.

There are two issues I seem to be unable to solve:

1. It is my understanding that I would need to somehow compress the `public/codes_out` directory in order to actually export it to a real user. I have heard that gzip (at least that's what I think it was called) can do this job quite well, but it has issues with Heroku. If this is the case then is there another compressor that I can use to compress this folder?
2. How can I actually get the User to download the compressed folder? I have tried `send_file '/public/codes_out', :x_sendfile=>true`, but unfortunately I can't send it like this because it isn't compressed.

If it helps at all, these QR Codes are all just simple PNGs, I have tried using Dragonfly and looked at Paperclip, but wasn't sure if either was actually useful for getting an entire directory downloaded at once like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this algorithm:

```
Dir["*"].each do |file|
  if File.directory?(file)
    `zip -r "#{file}.zip" "#{file}"`
  end
end
```

This allowed me to zip the entire directory, allowing me to target a single file and download it with this command in my controller:

```
send_file(Rails.root.join('public', 'codes_out.zip'), :type=>"application/zip" , :x_sendfile=>true)
```